# How to add icons to my list view ? Beside each of the text. (left side)

Tags: android, android-listview

This from the activity   myVenue.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_venue);

    drawerListViewItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.items);
    drawerListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer1);
    drawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.drawer_listview_item, drawerListViewItems));
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout1);
    actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout,
            R.drawable.icon_css, R.string.drawer_open,
            R.string.drawer_close);

    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    drawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

}
```

This from the layour  activity_my_venue.xml

```
  <ListView 

    android:id="@+id/left_drawer1"
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="#666"      
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:background="#333"
    android:paddingLeft="15sp"
    android:paddingRight="15sp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    >

    </ListView>
```

Anybody can teach me how to add an icon to each of the items that shown at the ListView and also how to make it bigger between the Listview divider.

Comment: You can use custom ListView. Refer @ http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

Comment: u need custom adapter...make adapter and extend base adapter ..google once

Answer (score 0):

http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-baseadapter/

```
you need to use custom BaseAdapter to do so.try the above link it will help you.
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create an adapter, and set that to your listview. Take a look here :
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#AdapterViews

Answer (score 0):

Add this custom.xml to res/layout :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip" >

    <!-- Image icon sebelah kiri -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/picture_menu_on_listview"
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip" />
</LinearLayout>

<!-- label Menu Nomor -->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/urutan_makanan_ayam_listview_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:text="Menu no : "
    android:textColor="#040404"
    android:typeface="sans"
    android:textSize="12dip"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<!-- nomor urutan -->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/urutan_makanan_ayam_listview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/urutan_makanan_ayam_listview_label"
    android:textColor="#040404"
    android:typeface="sans"
    android:textSize="12dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"
     />

<!-- label nama makanan -->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/nama_makanan_ayam_listview_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/urutan_makanan_ayam_listview_label"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:text="Menu : "
    android:textColor="#040404"
    android:typeface="sans"
    android:textSize="12dip"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<!-- menu makanan -->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/nama_makanan_ayam_listview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/urutan_makanan_ayam_listview"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/nama_makanan_ayam_listview_label"
    android:textColor="#040404"
    android:typeface="sans"
    android:textSize="12dip"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<!-- label harga makanan -->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/harga_makanan_ayam_listview_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/nama_makanan_ayam_listview_label"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:text="Harga : "
    android:textColor="#040404"
    android:typeface="sans"
    android:textSize="12dip"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<!-- harga makanan -->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/harga_makanan_ayam_listview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/nama_makanan_ayam_listview"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/harga_makanan_ayam_listview_label"
    android:textColor="#040404"
    android:typeface="sans"
    android:textSize="12dip"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<!-- Image icon sebelah kanan -->
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/arrow_on_listview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:padding="1dp" />

<!-- ratingbar icon sebelah kanan -->
<RatingBar 
    android:id="@+id/rating_makanan_ayam"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/arrow_on_listview"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:rating="4"
    android:stepSize="1"
    style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
    android:isIndicator="true"
    />

  <!-- android:padding="5dp" -->

  </RelativeLayout>
```

add this to you MainActivity.java :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
String [] urutan_makanan_sotong;
String [] jenis_menu_sotong;
String [] price_menu_sotong;
TypedArray pic_menu;
BaseAdapter adapt;

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.left_drawer1);

    Resources r = getResources();       
    urutan_makanan_sotong = r.getStringArray(R.array.urutan_makanan_sotong);        
    jenis_menu_sotong = r.getStringArray(R.array.jenis_menu_sotong);        
    price_menu_sotong = r.getStringArray(R.array.price_menu_sotong);        
    pic_menu = r.obtainTypedArray(R.array.pic_menu_sotong);
            final ListView daftar_menu_sotong = 
            (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_menu_ayam);
    adapt = new ListViewAdapter(this, urutan_makanan_sotong, 
             jenis_menu_sotong, price_menu_sotong, pic_menu);
    daftar_menu_sotong.setAdapter(adapt);
     }

        public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    String [] urutan;
    String [] jns_menu_sotong;
    String [] price_sotong;
    TypedArray picture_menu;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    Context context;

    public ListViewAdapter(Context context, String [] urutan_makanan_sotong,
             String [] jenis_menu_sotong, String [] price_menu_sotong, 
             TypedArray pic_menu){
        this.context = context;
        this.urutan = urutan_makanan_sotong;
        this.jns_menu_sotong = jenis_menu_sotong;
        this.price_sotong = price_menu_sotong;
        this.picture_menu = pic_menu;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return jenis_menu_sotong.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        TextView txt_urutan;
        TextView txt_menu;
        TextView txt_price;
        ImageView img_menu;
        ImageView img_arrow;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(
                    Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom, parent, false);

        img_menu = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(
                    R.id.picture_menu_on_listview);
        txt_urutan = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(
                    R.id.urutan_makanan_ayam_listview);
        txt_menu = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(
                    R.id.nama_makanan_ayam_listview);
        txt_price = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(
                    R.id.harga_makanan_ayam_listview);
        img_arrow = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(
                    R.id.arrow_on_listview);

        txt_urutan.setText(urutan_makanan_sotong[pos]);
        txt_menu.setText(jenis_menu_sotong[pos]);
        txt_price.setText(price_menu_sotong[pos]);
        img_menu.setImageResource(pic_menu.getResourceId(pos, -1));
        img_arrow.setImageResource(R.drawable.nav_icon);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```